# Create a function that receives data from one structure and transfers it from another

Tags: rust, struct

I have two Task and Variables structures. The fields in Variables are filled in from a yaml file, and the Task structure exists to create a query. How do I make the Task structure receive field data from the Variables Structure?

I expect the Task structure to receive data in its fields from the Variables structure

```
pub struct Task {
    id: u16,
    unit_id: u8,
    protocol: ProtocolType,
    command: CommandType,
    start: u16,
    count: u16,
    data: Vec<u16>,
    mreq: Option<ModbusRequest>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Clone)]
pub struct Variables {
    pub storage: String,
    pub id: u16,
    pub unit_id: u8,
    pub name: u16,
    pub start: u16,
}
```